# Second screen is recognized by xrandr but stays black

Tags: opensuse, display, xrandr

After two weeks of not using my machine I have the following issue:

- I have two connected screens
- The second one (Apple screen) is connected and recognized by `xrandr`, but stays black.
- If I change the display config the working screen even only shows half of the output, so the system seems to think the Apple screen is working. However no of my ongoing `xrandr` efforts have switched it on.

What can I try to solve this problem?

OS: OpenSUSE Leap 15.1

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200     59.95 +  59.88
```

Comment: Have you disconnected both and tested them separately? Do both of them work individually?

Comment: @eblock: yes, the Apple screen also shows no output when used alone, the main one works in both ways

Comment: @AdminBee thanks! output is: Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: Maybe the Apple display is broken then.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I would be surprised as it worked perfectly fine 2 weeks ago and it was not used since then...

Comment: Does the Apple screen have two inputs and is listening on the wrong one? Could it be as simple?

Comment: xrandr output is now available formatted. @Fiximan no there is only one connection between screen and machine

Comment: @AdminBee I don't think DVI-I-1 should not show ("disconnected") if the wrong input is set on monitor. Monitor still reports correct resolution to the computer on all inputs.

Comment: sorry my bad, the xrandr output was wrong - see corrected version above with "connected"